# Is it pythonic to call the setter from the property

Tags: python, properties, setter

I am often using the `@property` decorator on classes where the attribute in question requires some calculation before being returned. My question is how to divide the responsibility between the `@property` and the `@attribute.setter` methods.

Example

```py
class TradingAlgo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._price = None

    @property
    def price(self):
        if self._price not None:
            return self._price

        price = some_calculation()

        # what to do here?

    @price.setter
    def price(self, value):
        price = validation_of_price(value)
        self._price = price
```

My question is what to do in the end of the `@property`-decorated `price` method? Is it okay to do

```py
self.price = price
return self._price
```

to trigger the `setter` method which does validation of the price variable before returning it? Or am I mixing what should be happening in the two methods?